# Export event log from a remote server to another shared folder

Tags: c#, event-log

I'm trying to filter the event log from the remote server and export it to another PC.

Here is the sample code.

```
SecureString pw = new NetworkCredential("user", "Password").SecurePassword;

EventLogSession session = new EventLogSession(
    "RemoteServer",  // Remote Server
    "domain",        // Domain
    "user",          // Username
    pw,
    SessionAuthentication.Default);

session.ExportLogAndMessages("", PathType.LogName, query, "d:\\testing\\log.evtx");
```

If the `targetFilePath`(d:\\testing\\log.evtx) is located in `RemoteServer`, the log is export successfully without any error.

But when the `targetFilePath` is "\\anotherPC\\Test\\log.evtx". It throw an exception

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'
```

The `user` can access both PC and Server export the event log without any problem.

The `user` can manually remote into `RemoteServer` and using Event Viewer to export to another `PC` shared folder.

How can I export the log to another PC without `UnauthorizedAccessException`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem after a few days.

I don't know why but if I export the log to the same machine, then use `File.Copy` to move the log. It works as expected.

```
session.ExportLogAndMessages("", PathType.LogName, queryString, "C:\\testing\\test.evtx");
File.Copy(@"\\RemoteServer\c$\testing\test.evtx", @"\\anotherPC\Test\test.evtx");
```